# ThreeJS Animation geometry doesn't update but position does?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, ecmascript-6, blender

I'll preface this by saying I'm new to Blender / 3DS MAX / ThreeJS and graphics programming.

I exported an animation of a Mutalisk (from StarCraft) flapping its wings from the StarCraft editor as an .m3 file, which I imported into Blender. Upon exporting, I am able to import the resulting .json into my ES6 application, but for some reason, using a THREE.Animation, while the position of the imported Mutalisk properly changes, it bobs around, the actual flapping of the Mutalisk object doesn't occur.

My renderer looks like this:

```
import THREE from 'three';

export default class Renderer {
  constructor(game, canvas) {
    this.game = game;
    this.canvas = canvas;

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, this.canvas.width / this.canvas.height, 1, 10000);
    this.camera.position.z = 2;
    this.camera.position.y = 1;

    this.clock = new THREE.Clock;

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvas });
    this.renderer.setSize( this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height );
  }

  // called by my Game class, which waits for the mesh to load before attempting to add it to the scene
  addMeshToScene(mesh) {
    this.mesh = mesh;

    this.scene.add(this.mesh);

    this.animation = new THREE.Animation(
      this.mesh,
      this.mesh.geometry.animations[ 2 ]
    );

    this.animation.play();
  }

  renderFrame() {
    THREE.AnimationHandler.update(this.clock.getDelta());

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}
```

And here's the render. As I said, the Mutalisk in my browser is bouncing along the Y-axis, but not flapping.

[image: mutalisk]

Can anyone shed some light on why the movement happens, but not the flapping?

Edit: here are my Blender export settings.

[image: blender settings]

Comment: Interestingly, I just noticed that all of my animations[] have 44 steps each. I'm going to guess this might be an issue with my Blender export.

Comment: Can you report what animation parameters you chose in the exporter ?

Comment: How do you instantiate the `Renderer`? Where do you call `addMeshToScene`, and where `renderFrame`?

Comment: In my Game class, there is a setup method that just calls `this.setRenderer(new Renderer(this, this.canvas))`. That part of the code isn't the problem, I don't think.

In Blender: Geometry: vertices, faces, normals, UVs, bones, skinning. Apply Modifiers (checked) Geometry UInt16Array. Skeletal animation, Rest. Embed animation. Settings, Copy textures.

Comment: I created a repo with my current code. Everything I'm talking about is in `client/js/renderer.js`

Comment: https://github.com/sent1nel/gamework-es6 woops, forgot the link

Comment: http://sandbox.sent1nel.me/ and here is a link to the app running on my own server

Comment: I figured out how to use a `THREE.SkeletonHelper` to show the bones of the skeleton. The reason for the bouncing is that the bones are actually moving, but it seems the mesh isn't morphing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was that materials have to be in skinning mode to properly wrap the skeleton. When I created my mesh from JSON, I had to set `material.skinning = true`

```
import THREE from 'three';

export default class Mesh {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.loaded = false;
    this.filepath = `./meshes/${this.name}.json`
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(this.filepath, (geometry) => {
      this.geometry = geometry;
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff, wireframe: true } );
      material.skinning = true; // this is where the magic happens
      this.mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);
      this.loaded = true;
    });
  }
}
```